# Unable to open file in Nougat using custom file provider

Tags: android, android-7.0-nougat, internal-storage

I am trying to open a file in nougat using file provider, saw some examples and added provider to manifest and created the providerpath xml as follows:

```
<provider
    android:name="android.support.v4.content.FileProvider"
    android:authorities="${applicationId}.provider"
    android:exported="false"
    android:grantUriPermissions="true">
    <meta-data
        android:name="android.support.FILE_PROVIDER_PATHS"
        android:resource="@xml/provider_paths"/>
</provider>
```

provider_path.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<paths xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <external-path
        name="/"
        path="." />
</paths>
```

Code to open the file:

```
            Intent intent = new Intent();
            intent.setAction(android.content.Intent.ACTION_VIEW);
            File file = new File(path);

            MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
            String ext = file.getName().substring(file.getName().indexOf(".") + 1);
            String type = mime.getMimeTypeFromExtension(ext);
            Log.d(TAG, file.getAbsolutePath() + "mime " + type + " ext " + ext + "uri file " + FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    file).toString());
            Uri ur = UriHelper.getNougatUri(file);
            Log.d(TAG, "uri2 " + ur);
            intent.setDataAndType(FileProvider.getUriForFile(context,
                    BuildConfig.APPLICATION_ID + ".provider",
                    file), type);
            context.startActivity(intent);
```

Logcat:

```
08-09 12:04:39.728 18288-18288/com.app.tod D/ChatAdapter1: /storage/emulated/0/com.app.tod/Media/sent/08-09-2017 12:04 PM.jpegmime image/jpeg ext jpeguri file content://com.app.tod.provider/%2Fstorage%2Femulated%2F0%2Fcom.app.tod%2F/com.app.toado/Media/sent/08-09-2017%2012%3A04%20PM.jpeg
08-09 12:04:39.729 18288-18288/com.app.tod D/ChatAdapter1: uri2 content://com.app.tod.provider/storage/emulated/0/com.app.tod/Media/sent/08-09-2017 12:04 PM.jpeg
```

When i click on the file it goes to the gallery and says Image cannot be loaded,
the image exists at this path-

```
/storage/emulated/0/com.app.tod/Media/sent/08-09-2017 12:04 PM.jpeg
```

Can someone please tell me how can i access all the files in the folder i created for my app at /storage/emulated/0/com.app.tod/

Also if i want to open a file in some other location in internal storage is there a way?

Thanks.

Comment: simply use `ContentResolver` API to get `Uri` content

Comment: @pskink can u please give some link or some code on how to do this in my case ?

Comment: @pskink also i dont only want to open jpeg or video files, i also want to open documents like pdf etc

Comment: @pskink thanks but i am not able to understand.. there is a fileassetdecriptor which returns data but i am not able to figure out how can i open that file using it. can u check my code i posted and tell me where could i be wrong? is my provider_path.xml code fine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When i click on the file it goes to the gallery and says Image cannot be loaded

You did not add `FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION` to the `Intent`, and so third-party apps cannot read the content identified by your `Uri`.

Also note that your `UriHelper.getNougatUri(file);` appears to be useless, as all you do with the result is log it to LogCat.

Comment: Thanks! could u please have a look at this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45628865/how-to-change-open-in-gallery-intent-to-done](question) too! i want to build an intent to pick both images and videos and instead of 'open' i want 'ok' or 'done' to display after selection is done